# How to assign one variable to other inside of an object vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I created a variable with a string inside an object and need to split it inside of other variable in the same object.

```
function dateRestore(){

    var date = document.querySelectorAll('.dateEvent');

    //console.log(date_fin);
    for (var i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {

        var start = {
            date: document.querySelectorAll('.date_in')[i],
            dateSstring: this.date.innerHTML.split(' ')//here I try to assign the variable date to variable dateSstring 
        };
        var finish = {
            date: document.querySelectorAll('.date_fin')[i]
        }
        alert(start.dateSstring.innerHTML);

    }
}
dateRestore();
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you elaborate on your expected result?

Comment: The string of 'date' variable is date in format 'day/month/year hour:minuts am/pm'. So I need to change the format. First I get the string to var date and after I want to split it in dateSstring. Other variable will be hourS: dateSstring[1], which is the time, after dayPeriod: dateSstring[2], which is the date and etc. If I do it inside of the object I can't assign one variable to another, appears an error "variable undefined".

Comment: With another words I need to do same like this:    var start = document.querySelectorAll('.date_in')[i],
   var dateSstring = start.innerHTML.split(' ');
   var hourS = dateSstring[1];
   var dayPeriod = dateSstring[2]; but inside of an object

Comment: There was a lot of strange bugs in your JS, check my editted version in snippet.

Comment: Here ? https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23392812 You should get a message where you can open edit and accept or reject it. Not sure if it is answer. Only edited your question.

Comment: Thanks! My question is more about how to assign one variable to other inside of object.

Example:

var example = {
  x: 1,
 b: x// so like this it obviously doesn't work, but how I can assign it?
}

Comment: I think you can, but assign property of declared array to same one is probably impossible in any language. And it sounds like code smell anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Store the result of `querySelectorAll()` and then re-use it when creating the objects:

```
function dateRestore(){
    var date = document.querySelectorAll('.dateEvent');

    for (var i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
        var date_in = document.querySelectorAll('.date_in')[i];

        if (!date_in) return; // make sure date_in exists

        var start = {
            date: date_in,
            dateSstring: date_in.innerHTML.split(' ')
        };
        var finish = {
            date: date_in
        };

        alert(start.dateSstring.innerHTML);
    }
}
dateRestore();
```